# Return 0 in PowerPC 32 bit

Tags: return, 32-bit, instructions, powerpc

I'm quite new to PPC and currently haven't been able to find the instruction to return 0 in PPC? I've done quite a bit of searching around and haven't really found anything of use, any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Do you mean "pay-per-click?"

Comment: @Marichyasana lol no...

Answer (score 2):

`r3` is generally the register that contains the result or the return of a function. In PowerPC, returning zero usually looks like this:

```
li r3, 0
blr
```

To break it down a bit, the instruction `li` will load `r3` with the immediate value of `0` and the instruction `blr` will handle branching to the address in the link register.